# How to use an object outside a method in java?

Tags: java, spring, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
public class Utilty
{
public DesiredCapabilities nologs()
{
DesiredCapabilities dcap= new DesiredCapabilities();
return dcap;
}
private static WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(dcap)
}
}
```

i want to use dcap object outside the method nologs but i am unable to do so.how to use dcap object?

Comment: Can you at least take the time to format the code?

Comment: You want to step back and learn java, before engaging in spring, selenium. Not knowing how to turn a local variable into a **class field**, sorry, you should be doing nothing else but work through those https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ tutorials for quite some days.

Comment: do some research before posting here

Answer (score 0):

Construct an instance of Utility, and then call dcap(). Eg:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new Utility ().dcap();
 ...
```

Or make the dcap method static like your driver method.